# Q: Overflow menu with custom component instead of "the three dots"

Tags: wix-react-native-navigation

I know how to create an overflow menu in the top bar using the `showAsAction` option as described here: https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/docs/stack#overflow-menu. But is it possible to use a custom component instead of the "three dots" icon? I have a custom component that displays the user's initials in a circle, and I want the overflow menu to appear when it is tapped. How can that be achieved? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best option here is to show the custom component as a button and when it's clicked - create your own menu implementation and show it in an Overlay.

Comment: Thanks, @guy.gc. As you suggested, I show a custom overflow menu with `Navigation.showOverlay()` and every menu item calls `Navigation.dissmissOverlay()` as well as performing their respective tasks.